# Non LuckyCoin descendant alt-coins with fair "lucky blocks"?

Tags: mining-reward, dogecoin, random

Dogecoin just dropped the "lucky block" stuff after it was found out the "luckiness" wasn't entirely random - multiminers were waiting for the lucky blocks to appear and dropping their hashing power onto Doge's network all of a sudden to ensure they won the extra-bonus, then jumping out to mine another more profitable (for the moment) coin.

I know 42coin has fully deterministic bonus blocks, so most probably the multipools are grabbing those as well - wouldn't be surprised if they're dropped soon for same reasons.

But after checking the graphs of altcoin ancestries, it seems to me all coins with lucky blocks descend ultimately from LuckyCoin, so almost certainly have the same deffect.

Is there an alt-coin with lucky blocks that doesn't descend from LuckyCoin? Another question: Have randomness tests ever been applied to these coins to verify both their appearance and the amount given are really random?